# fetch or extract data from Json to php and insert into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, xml, json, yql

Can any one help me out how to fetch the data from this json script generated from yql . I want to store the data to mysql which is grabbed from here... I want to extract or grab datas AskRealtime, BidRealtime, LastTradeDate, LastTradePriceOnly, LastTradeTime, Ask

```
<?php
session_start();
query= Insert into table .....value ...
?>
```

I want to do something like the above script from the below json . better if i can directly print the extracted data to the same page in one of the html table without sending it to mysql and pulling data from there ...

`{

```
"query": {
    "count": 5,
    "created": "2012-05-11T01:14:55Z",
    "lang": "en-US",
    "diagnostics": {
        "publiclyCallable": "true",
        "redirect": {
            "from": "http://datatables.org/alltables.env",
            "status": "301",
            "content": "http://www.datatables.org/alltables.env"
        },
        "url": [
            {
                "execution-start-time": "425",
                "execution-stop-time": "865",
                "execution-time": "440",
                "proxy": "DEFAULT",
                "content": "http://datatables.org/alltables.env"
            },
            {
                "execution-start-time": "884",
                "execution-stop-time": "1097",
                "execution-time": "213",
                "proxy": "DEFAULT",
                "content": "http://www.datatables.org/yahoo/finance/yahoo.finance.quotes.xml"
            },
            {
                "execution-start-time": "1307",
                "execution-stop-time": "1307",
                "execution-time": "0",
                "proxy": "DEFAULT",
                "content": "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?f=aa2bb2b3b4cc1c3c6c8dd1d2ee1e7e8e9ghjkg1g3g4g5g6ii5j1j3j4j5j6k1k2k4k5ll1l2l3mm2m3m4m5m6m7m8nn4opp1p2p5p6qrr1r2r5r6r7ss1s7t1t7t8vv1v7ww1w4xy&s=XAUUSD%3DX,XAGUSD%3DX,PLN12.NYM,PAK12.NYM,USDCAD%3DX"
            }
        ],
        "query": {
            "execution-start-time": "1105",
            "execution-stop-time": "1308",
            "execution-time": "203",
            "params": "{url=[http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?f=aa2bb2b3b4cc1c3c6c8dd1d2ee1e7e8e9ghjkg1g3g4g5g6ii5j1j3j4j5j6k1k2k4k5ll1l2l3mm2m3m4m5m6m7m8nn4opp1p2p5p6qrr1r2r5r6r7ss1s7t1t7t8vv1v7ww1w4xy&s=XAUUSD%3DX,XAGUSD%3DX,PLN12.NYM,PAK12.NYM,USDCAD%3DX]}",
            "content": "select * from csv where url=@url and columns='Ask,AverageDailyVolume,Bid,AskRealtime,BidRealtime,BookValue,Change&PercentChange,Change,Commission,ChangeRealtime,AfterHoursChangeRealtime,DividendShare,LastTradeDate,TradeDate,EarningsShare,ErrorIndicationreturnedforsymbolchangedinvalid,EPSEstimateCurrentYear,EPSEstimateNextYear,EPSEstimateNextQuarter,DaysLow,DaysHigh,YearLow,YearHigh,HoldingsGainPercent,AnnualizedGain,HoldingsGain,HoldingsGainPercentRealtime,HoldingsGainRealtime,MoreInfo,OrderBookRealtime,MarketCapitalization,MarketCapRealtime,EBITDA,ChangeFromYearLow,PercentChangeFromYearLow,LastTradeRealtimeWithTime,ChangePercentRealtime,ChangeFromYearHigh,PercebtChangeFromYearHigh,LastTradeWithTime,LastTradePriceOnly,HighLimit,LowLimit,DaysRange,DaysRangeRealtime,FiftydayMovingAverage,TwoHundreddayMovingAverage,ChangeFromTwoHundreddayMovingAverage,PercentChangeFromTwoHundreddayMovingAverage,ChangeFromFiftydayMovingAverage,PercentChangeFromFiftydayMovingAverage,Name,Notes,Open,PreviousClose,PricePaid,ChangeinPercent,PriceSales,PriceBook,ExDividendDate,PERatio,DividendPayDate,PERatioRealtime,PEGRatio,PriceEPSEstimateCurrentYear,PriceEPSEstimateNextYear,Symbol,SharesOwned,ShortRatio,LastTradeTime,TickerTrend,OneyrTargetPrice,Volume,HoldingsValue,HoldingsValueRealtime,YearRange,DaysValueChange,DaysValueChangeRealtime,StockExchange,DividendYield'"
        },
        "javascript": {
            "execution-time": "266",
            "instructions-used": "302754",
            "table-name": "yahoo.finance.quotes"
        },
        "warning": "Unable to sort response according to field 'Ask,Bid,AskRealtime,BidRealtime,LastTradeDate,LastTradePriceOnly,LastTradeTime'.",
        "user-time": "1373",
        "service-time": "653",
        "build-version": "27222"
    },
    "results": {
        "quote": [
            {
                "symbol": "XAUUSD=X",
                "Bid": "1590.9498",
                "AskRealtime": null,
                "BidRealtime": null,
                "LastTradeDate": "5/11/2012",
                "LastTradePriceOnly": "1590.5499",
                "LastTradeTime": "9:12pm",
                "Ask": "1590.15"
            },
            {
                "symbol": "XAGUSD=X",
                "Bid": null,
                "AskRealtime": null,
                "BidRealtime": null,
                "LastTradeDate": "5/10/2012",
                "LastTradePriceOnly": "29.136",
                "LastTradeTime": "5:27pm",
                "Ask": null
            },
            {
                "symbol": "PLN12.NYM",
                "Bid": null,
                "AskRealtime": "1486.50",
                "BidRealtime": "1486.00",
                "LastTradeDate": "5/11/2012",
                "LastTradePriceOnly": "1486.00",
                "LastTradeTime": "8:44pm",
                "Ask": null
            },
            {
                "symbol": "PAK12.NYM",
                "Bid": null,
                "AskRealtime": "616.00",
                "BidRealtime": "609.40",
                "LastTradeDate": "5/11/2012",
                "LastTradePriceOnly": "658.80",
                "LastTradeTime": "8:00pm",
                "Ask": null
            },
            {
                "symbol": "USDCAD=X",
                "Bid": "1.0033",
                "AskRealtime": null,
                "BidRealtime": null,
                "LastTradeDate": "5/11/2012",
                "LastTradePriceOnly": "1.0034",
                "LastTradeTime": "9:13pm",
                "Ask": "1.0035"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}`

The link to this json script is here [Json script generated by YQL](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20symbol,%20Ask,Bid,AskRealtime,BidRealtime,LastTradeDate,LastTradePriceOnly,LastTradeTime%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%22XAUUSD=X%22,%22XAGUSD=X%22,%22PLN12.NYM%22,%22PAK12.NYM%22,%22USDCAD=X%22%29%20%7C%20sort%28field=%22Ask,Bid,AskRealtime,BidRealtime,LastTradeDate,LastTradePriceOnly,LastTradeTime%22,%20descending=%22true%22%29%0A%09%09&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env&callback=forex)
The json script is verified from http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to take that JSON and be able to access the data within? To make the JSON a bit easier to use I would suggest using the following code which makes use of the [json_decode function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) which will transform the JSON into a php usable array. (I included the echo statement so that you can see what the resulting associative array looks like)

```
$yql_json =
'{
"query": {
    "count": 5,
    "created": "2012-05-11T01:14:55Z",
    "lang": "en-US",
    "diagnostics": {
        "publiclyCallable": "true",
        "redirect": {
            "from": "http://datatables.org/alltables.env",
            "status": "301",
            "content": "http://www.datatables.org/alltables.env"
        },
        "url": [
            {
                "execution-start-time": "425",
                "execution-stop-time": "865",
                "execution-time": "440",
                "proxy": "DEFAULT",
                "content": "http://datatables.org/alltables.env"
            },
            {
                "execution-start-time": "884",
                "execution-stop-time": "1097",
                "execution-time": "213",
                "proxy": "DEFAULT",
                "content": "http://www.datatables.org/yahoo/finance/yahoo.finance.quotes.xml"
            },
            {
                "execution-start-time": "1307",
                "execution-stop-time": "1307",
                "execution-time": "0",
                "proxy": "DEFAULT",
                "content": "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?f=aa2bb2b3b4cc1c3c6c8dd1d2ee1e7e8e9ghjkg1g3g4g5g6ii5j1j3j4j5j6k1k2k4k5ll1l2l3mm2m3m4m5m6m7m8nn4opp1p2p5p6qrr1r2r5r6r7ss1s7t1t7t8vv1v7ww1w4xy&s=XAUUSD%3DX,XAGUSD%3DX,PLN12.NYM,PAK12.NYM,USDCAD%3DX"
            }
        ],
        "query": {
            "execution-start-time": "1105",
            "execution-stop-time": "1308",
            "execution-time": "203",
            "params": "{url=[http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?f=aa2bb2b3b4cc1c3c6c8dd1d2ee1e7e8e9ghjkg1g3g4g5g6ii5j1j3j4j5j6k1k2k4k5ll1l2l3mm2m3m4m5m6m7m8nn4opp1p2p5p6qrr1r2r5r6r7ss1s7t1t7t8vv1v7ww1w4xy&s=XAUUSD%3DX,XAGUSD%3DX,PLN12.NYM,PAK12.NYM,USDCAD%3DX]}",
            "content": "select * from csv where url=@url and columns=\'Ask,AverageDailyVolume,Bid,AskRealtime,BidRealtime,BookValue,Change&PercentChange,Change,Commission,ChangeRealtime,AfterHoursChangeRealtime,DividendShare,LastTradeDate,TradeDate,EarningsShare,ErrorIndicationreturnedforsymbolchangedinvalid,EPSEstimateCurrentYear,EPSEstimateNextYear,EPSEstimateNextQuarter,DaysLow,DaysHigh,YearLow,YearHigh,HoldingsGainPercent,AnnualizedGain,HoldingsGain,HoldingsGainPercentRealtime,HoldingsGainRealtime,MoreInfo,OrderBookRealtime,MarketCapitalization,MarketCapRealtime,EBITDA,ChangeFromYearLow,PercentChangeFromYearLow,LastTradeRealtimeWithTime,ChangePercentRealtime,ChangeFromYearHigh,PercebtChangeFromYearHigh,LastTradeWithTime,LastTradePriceOnly,HighLimit,LowLimit,DaysRange,DaysRangeRealtime,FiftydayMovingAverage,TwoHundreddayMovingAverage,ChangeFromTwoHundreddayMovingAverage,PercentChangeFromTwoHundreddayMovingAverage,ChangeFromFiftydayMovingAverage,PercentChangeFromFiftydayMovingAverage,Name,Notes,Open,PreviousClose,PricePaid,ChangeinPercent,PriceSales,PriceBook,ExDividendDate,PERatio,DividendPayDate,PERatioRealtime,PEGRatio,PriceEPSEstimateCurrentYear,PriceEPSEstimateNextYear,Symbol,SharesOwned,ShortRatio,LastTradeTime,TickerTrend,OneyrTargetPrice,Volume,HoldingsValue,HoldingsValueRealtime,YearRange,DaysValueChange,DaysValueChangeRealtime,StockExchange,DividendYield\'"
        },
        "javascript": {
            "execution-time": "266",
            "instructions-used": "302754",
            "table-name": "yahoo.finance.quotes"
        },
        "warning": "Unable to sort response according to field \'Ask,Bid,AskRealtime,BidRealtime,LastTradeDate,LastTradePriceOnly,LastTradeTime\'.",
        "user-time": "1373",
        "service-time": "653",
        "build-version": "27222"
    },
    "results": {
        "quote": [
            {
                "symbol": "XAUUSD=X",
                "Bid": "1590.9498",
                "AskRealtime": null,
                "BidRealtime": null,
                "LastTradeDate": "5/11/2012",
                "LastTradePriceOnly": "1590.5499",
                "LastTradeTime": "9:12pm",
                "Ask": "1590.15"
            },
            {
                "symbol": "XAGUSD=X",
                "Bid": null,
                "AskRealtime": null,
                "BidRealtime": null,
                "LastTradeDate": "5/10/2012",
                "LastTradePriceOnly": "29.136",
                "LastTradeTime": "5:27pm",
                "Ask": null
            },
            {
                "symbol": "PLN12.NYM",
                "Bid": null,
                "AskRealtime": "1486.50",
                "BidRealtime": "1486.00",
                "LastTradeDate": "5/11/2012",
                "LastTradePriceOnly": "1486.00",
                "LastTradeTime": "8:44pm",
                "Ask": null
            },
            {
                "symbol": "PAK12.NYM",
                "Bid": null,
                "AskRealtime": "616.00",
                "BidRealtime": "609.40",
                "LastTradeDate": "5/11/2012",
                "LastTradePriceOnly": "658.80",
                "LastTradeTime": "8:00pm",
                "Ask": null
            },
            {
                "symbol": "USDCAD=X",
                "Bid": "1.0033",
                "AskRealtime": null,
                "BidRealtime": null,
                "LastTradeDate": "5/11/2012",
                "LastTradePriceOnly": "1.0034",
                "LastTradeTime": "9:13pm",
                "Ask": "1.0035"
            }
        ]
    }
}
}';

$yql_results = json_decode($yql_json, true);
echo "<pre>".print_r($yql_results, true)."</pre>";
```

The $yql_json input is the json itself as a string (however you collect and store it) and the value of true being passed into the function makes the function return an associative array that gets stored in $yql_result. After this you can access all of it's items easily. I hope I answered at least part of your question. Good luck on your project.